# How to append any element with class to the first instance of another class based on its location on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My ***CMS*** uses widgets to display products and I cannot manipulate the code in those widgets, but I can add code around them. I would like to add html blocks below the widgets and use ***JS*** to remove, clone, and append to the code inside the widgets. The rule would be that the html blocks would need to append themselves to the first instance of a class in the code before each block.

I can only make this work right now using a simple set up where there's only the one widget with one block:

```js
var block = jQuery('.block').remove().clone();
jQuery('.widget').eq(1).append(block);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
</ol>
<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<li class="block">Item C</li>
```

Which results in the following output in the **DOM**

```html
<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
  <li>Item C</li>
</ol>
```

But when I have multiple widgets and blocks, the multiple blocks all end up appending to the last widget instead of the first widget that appears before each block.

```js
var block = jQuery('.block').remove().clone();
jQuery('.widget').eq(1).append(block);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
</ol>
<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<li class="block">Item C</li>


<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item X</li>
  <li>Item Y</li>
</ol>
<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<li class="block">Item Z</li>
```

In the above code example, I'm trying to get Item C to append to the widget above it and Item Z to append to the first widget above that one, and so on. Ideally I could have an unlimited number of blocks appended to widgets this way. Right now this code is appending both Item C and Item Z to the last instance of class=widget on the page.

#### ***** UPDATE ******

I need this to work even if the `.widget` list is surrounded by 3 `<div>`s (which I missed originally), so the untouchable code looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ol class="widget">....</ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried it and couldn't get it working - only managed to remove the block rather than remove and append: https://jsfiddle.net/2obxhc35/

Comment: please check my solution

Comment: Will this work if there are 3 DIVS surrounding the list like this? It seems to break in this case... https://jsfiddle.net/2obxhc35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to find each `.block` and then find the previous `.widget` and then append the `.block` to the `.widget` found.

#### How can we do this?

Well just follow this idea:

1. Get each `.block` with `$('.block').each()`
2. Remove `.block` out of the DOM using `$(this).remove();`
3. Append the `.block` to the previous `.widget` with `$('.widget').eq(index).append(block);`

```js
$('.block').each(function(index, value) {
  let block = $(this).remove();
  $('.widget').eq(index).append(block);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
</ol>

<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<li class="block">Item C</li>


<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ol class="widget">
        <li>Item X</li>
        <li>Item Y</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<li class="block">Item Z</li>
```

#### Alternative:

1. Get each `.block` with `$('.block').each()`
2. Get previous `.widget` using `$(this).prev('.widget')`
3. Remove `.block` out of the DOM using `$(this).remove();`
4. Append the `.block` to the previous `.widget` with `widget.append(block)`

Check this implementation:

```js
$('.block').each(function() {
  let widget = $(this).prev('.widget');
  let block = $(this).remove();
  widget.append(block);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
</ol>

<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<li class="block">Item C</li>


<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item X</li>
  <li>Item Y</li>
</ol>

<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->
<li class="block">Item Z</li>
```

Comment: Did you really, litterally copy and paste msg's answer and then change a few identifiers?

Comment: Using .eq() method worked for me in the updated scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on each `.block` separately and search for the previous `.widget` instead of using indexes:

```js
jQuery('.block').each(function() {
  let target = $(this).prev('.widget');
  let block = $(this).remove();
  target.append(block);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
</ol>
<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<li class="block">Item C</li>


<!-- BEGIN UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<ol class="widget">
  <li>Item X</li>
  <li>Item Y</li>
</ol>
<!-- END UNTOUCHABLE WIDGET CODE -->

<li class="block">Item Z</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't describe what led to this not working.  So that is my intent with this answer.

From the jQuery documentation about the `.eq()` method:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object **from one element within that
>   set**. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
>   set.

That results in this call `jQuery('.widget').eq(1).append(block);` does exactly as you've describe.

You'll need to iterate over the either the `block` OR the `widget` whichever makes more sense to you.